# How to zoom a part of an image upon being loaded?

Tags: html, css

I have these following divs with images inside, how am I able to zoom on certain parts of the image upon being loaded using css?

```css
#img-div-one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#img-div-two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img id="img-div-one"src="https://www.myperfectcv.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/business-cv-sample.jpg"></div>
<div><img id="img-div-two"src="https://static.developer.intuit.com/images/Brand-Sample.jpg"></div>
```

The first image must be
[Only the top half shown and zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXDyn.png)

The second image must be
[Half of the image is shown and zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGAMl.png)

I have seen tutorials for zooming an image using lens but those are not what I need, the image must be zoomed in when loaded in html

Comment: I don't understand how the images should be zoomed. It might help to include an example of the result you want. Do you mind adding one?

Comment: Hi showdev, I did included an example here is one for img-div-one https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXDyn.png. The image in the div is fitted and shows the whole image. What I need is for it is to be 'zoomed in' or show a larger portion of the top half of that image. The image should show only the upper top for the first div not the whole image